# How to concate two 3D matrices in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

Suppose I have two matrices A and B that are 3d. `A = 49x49x18 B = 49x49x24` After concatenation I want to see the `C = 49x49x42` as the concatenation of A and B at the third dimension.

How would I do that at matlab ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the [cat](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html) function specifying dimension 3

```
C = cat(3, A, B)
```